# Alternative ways to pass embed variables

Tags: embeds

Is there an alternate way to pass embed variables other than passing them as attributes?

Comment: You know you can put a complete module tag inside a parameter of an embed, right?

Answer (score 3):

Not natively I believe.

I typically use [Stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/) to do this nowadays. It will give you persistent variables as well as template inheritance so you can do things like this.

**Wrapper template**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//use.typekit.com" />

    {if "{exp:stash:not_empty name='st_html_title'}"}<title>{exp:stash:get name="st_html_title"} - Site name</title>{if:else}<title>Site name</title>{/if}

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{site_url}/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="{site_url}/assets/css/screen.css" />

</head>

    <div id="maincontent" role="main">

        {!-- built wisth stash and template partial approach--}
        {exp:stash:get name="content"}

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Partial template**

```
{!-- Layout used --}
{stash:embed:layouts:page}

{!-- Meta data --}
{exp:stash:set name="st_html_title"}Products{/exp:stash:set}

{!-- Build list --}
{exp:stash:set_list name="st_products_list"}
    {exp:channel:entries disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|trackbacks" channel="products" status="open" orderby="date" sort="desc" limit="10"}
        {stash:st_item_title}{title}{/stash:st_item_title}
        {stash:st_item_summary}{cf_product_summary}{/stash:st_item_summary}
    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{!-- Build page content --}
{exp:stash:set name="content"}

    {exp:stash:get_list name="st_products_list" prefix="stashprefix"}

        {if count == "1"}<ul>{/if}
            <li>
                <h2><a href="{st_url}">{st_title}</a></h2>
                <p>{st_item_summary}</p>
            </li>
        {if count == total_results}</ul>{/if}

        {!-- if no results --}
        {if stashprefix:no_results}<p>No Products Found</p>{/if}

    {/exp:stash:get_list}

{/exp:stash:set}
```

It takes a bit of time to wrap your head around that approach but it is worth it IMHO. Here are a few resources to get you started:

- [Mark Croxton on Speaker Deck](https://speakerdeck.com/croxton)
- [James Smith on Stash](http://www.jamessmith.co.uk/articles/expressionengine-stash-tutorials)

Comment: I can't use `{stash:embed}` unfortunately.

Comment: Regular embeds would work just fine as well.